# python ImportError: No module named win32file

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to build chromium on Windows10, I get:

> ImportError: No module named win32file

How to solve this?

Answer (score 22):

My solution is: `python -m pip install pywin32`.
Then you will see module win32file in the path of C:/python27/Lib/site-packages/win32file.pyd